# cannot put the output in the written txt file in python

Tags: python, file-io, jupyter-notebook, fwrite

I am new to python and I tried to firstly create a new empty file with the help of python, for example:

```
f=open('new.txt','x')
```

After creating this file, I wanted to write my output, which appears after running the code below, inside of the new.txt file:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(0,i):
            print(i,end=' ')
    print('\n')
```

However, I did not succeed with it using f.write function. Could you please advice me how to make it using f.write or another way?

Thanks in advance for your time and comprehension!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("new.txt", "w") as f:  # opens a new file and gets you ready to write to it (hence the 'w', it stands for write)
    for i in range(1,5):
        for j in range(0,i):
            print(i,end=' ')
            f.write(f"{i} ")  # write what you wanted to print
        print('\n')
        f.write("\n")  # again write what you wanted to print
        
# after this code executes python will automatically close the stream to the file (you do not need to do f.close() )
```

I left the prints in there so you can see what is being written to the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have created the file, to write, all you need to do is this:

```
with open('new.txt', 'a') as the_file:
  for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(0,i):
            the_file.write(str(i) + " ")
    the_file.write('\n')
```

Let me break it down:

1. The first line opens the txt file for you to write in it.
2. Then you loop through and write what you want to write. Notice how I changed the fourth line to `the_file.write(str(i)+" ")`. This is because you can only use strings inside the write() function.

Running this, you get:

```
1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4
```

Inside your txt file. Hope you found this helpful :D